# disable breakpoint hit messages in gdb

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, verbosity

I have a simple c++ loop I'm debugging with gdb, and I want to **disable the messages informing me of a breakpoint hit**. I've tried several gdb flags like `-q` and `set verbose off` but none worked. Here is my gdb script:

```
break file.c:27
run
set $i=0
while ($i < 8)
    print counter
    cont
    set $i = $i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I missed the following solution:

```
break file.c:27
commands
silent
end
run
set $i=0
while ($i < 8)
    print counter
    cont
    set $i = $i + 1
end
```